# ASP.NET Core MVC - Create Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm following along in a book (while learning C#) and the Security Controller for this MVC project has these lines of code.

```
AppIdentityRole role = new AppIdentityRole();
role.Name = "Manager";
role.Description = "Can perform CRUD operations.";
IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(role).Result;
```

in MS VS 2019 Comm Ed. it throws an error

Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EmployeeManager.MVC.Security.AppIdentityRole' to 'EmployeeManager.MVC.Security.AppIdentityUser'    EmployeeManager.MVC

it is part of the system in chapter 3

https://github.com/Apress/beg-database-prog-using-asp.net-core-3/tree/master/Chapter_03

My understanding is that the code is trying to create a new role in underlying security layer and the SQL database Northwind.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which line gives you that error? Are you sure you copied the exactly exactly the same way into your own app? And by the way, that code is handling async code improperly. If a book has errors that obvious, are you sure you want to use it to learn from? Who knows what other bad habits it might teach...

Comment: can you update your code to see the definition of roleManager?

Comment: Thanks Ziv for asking that question - I screwed up when defining it through a copy & paste and old eyes that didn't catch my error.   Mason - thanks for your input, I have found some errors in the book but, through fixing them I've also learned more than the original material intended.